# Having a route button pre-selected on launch

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a router page that has 2 buttons and each one of them calls its corresponding js function that renders text. When launching the page the user has to click either button for a function to be called. Buttons are "short" and "long". I want "short" to be enabled by default but the user should still be able to change between "long" and "short".

```
import {Link, resolvePath, useMatch, useResolvedPath} from "react-router-dom"

export default function Selector() {
    return (
        <div className="bar">
            <ul>
                <CustomLink to="/short">Short</CustomLink>
                <CustomLink to="/long">Long</CustomLink>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}


function CustomLink({to, children, ...props}) {
    const resolvedPath = useResolvedPath(to)
    const isActive = useMatch({ path: resolvedPath.pathname, end: true})
    return (
        <li className={isActive ? "active" : ""}>
            <Link to={to} {...props}>
                {children}</Link>
        </li>
    )
}

        {/* Displaying the result*/}
        <div className="container1">
          <Selector/>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/short" element = {<Short/>}/>
              <Route path="/long" element = {<Long/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </div>
```

Whatever I tried so far locks the page on "short" and doesn't allow the user to switch to "long".